# Rust Deref vs Implementing Iterators over inner types

Tags: rust, iterator

Here is a toy struct containing a vector

```rust
struct SizedVec {
    items: Vec<u32>,
    cap: usize,
}
```

I wanted to have iteration functions on `SizedVec` such that they will work as if I am iterating over items directly.

However, I was not sure which traits I should implement: are `Iterator` and `IntoIterator` enough? There are a lot of traits in [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#traits)
and they seemed a bit complicated and tedious.

Then I saw that I could implement `Deref` and `DerefMut` and get all those functions for free using deref coercion:

Sure enough, after doing this:

```rust
impl Deref for SizedVec {
    type Target = Vec<u32>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.items
    }
}

impl DerefMut for SizedVec {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.items
    }
}
```

I can use all the iterators I want. But I want to implement a custom logic for push, but `DeRef` already gave me a push. But according to the docs I should be fine because apparently the lookup is done for each type in order

```rust
impl SizedVec {
    fn from_size(size: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            items: vec![],
            cap: size,
        }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, item: u32) {
        if self.items.len() < self.cap {
            self.items.push(item);
        }else {
            self.items.pop();
            self.items.push(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And this seems to work,

```
fn main () {
    let mut svec = SizedVec::from_size(2); // Custom function I implemented
    svec.push(2);
    svec.push(3);
    svec.push(4);
    svec.iter_mut().for_each(|item| {*item = *item + 2});
    println!("{}", svec); // Items: [4, 6], Cap: 2 (Implemented Display so this works)
}
```

This all seems to work very well, but my question is: is this a good idea? Will I have problems if i convert my `SizedVec` to a generic type?

If this is a bad idea, is there a simple way I can get all the iteration/map functionality of the inner vector items onto the enclosing struct ?

Also, are there any performance considerations to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Deref` is fine since your structure is specifically a vec with additional invariants (so making it usable *as* a vec seems sensible) but `DerefMut` seems like a rather bad idea as it will let the caller leak the internal `Vec` (as a mutable reference) and break your invariants.

One option might be to `Deref` to a slice (instead of a vec), in which case `DerefMut` will also get you a slice, which has pretty severe restrictions and thus won't be able to break your invariants. That will mean you may need to reimplement inherent `Vec` methods, and won't be able to pass off as a `Vec`, though.

An other option would be to not implement `DerefMut` at all, and have more explicit methods for these. Also WRT iterables, note that you only need to implement `IntoIterator` and other iterator-yielding methods (`.iter()`, `.iter_mut()`): the result can just be whatever iterator the underlying collection returns.

Now I don't know what you meant by

> However, I was not sure which traits I should implement: are Iterator [...] enough?

You should not, under any circumstance, implement `Iterator` directly on your `SizedVec`. That is a terrible, terrible idea.

The iterator sub-traits are basically markers, they provide additional features over `Iterator` (but can't necessarily be implemented by every `Iterator` type). If you're delegating your iteration proper, the underlying iterator type will have likely have implemented those which are possible.